# XPages ApplicationLayout: get clicked value of selected drop down item in BannerLinks

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a drop down I want to use to select the province the user wants to work in (yep, I'm in Canada!).

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the value that is clicked, as I want to put that value in a session scope variable.

The code for the drop down is built that way for now:

```
 <xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
        <xe:basicContainerNode
            submitValue="provinceSwitch">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Québec"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Ontario"
                    submitValue="Ontario">
                </xe:basicLeafNode>

                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Maritimes"
                    submitValue="Maritimes">
                </xe:basicLeafNode>

                <xe:basicLeafNode label="West"
                    submitValue="West">
                </xe:basicLeafNode>

            </xe:this.children>
            <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(!!sessionScope.province) {
    sessionScope.province;
    } else {
    "Province";
    }}]]></xe:this.label>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>

<xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="langSwitch"
                            styleClass="lotusFirst">
                            <xe:this.label>
                                <![CDATA[#{javascript:if(!!sessionScope.lang)  {
    if(sessionScope.lang=="FR") {
        return "English";
    } else {
        return "Français";
    }
} else {
    return "English";
}}]]>
                            </xe:this.label>

                        </xe:basicLeafNode>

    <xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
```

I already have an eventHandler defined, used to select the language:

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="false"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="PanelAll">
                <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var submittedValue=context.getSubmittedValue();
if(submittedValue=="langSwitch") {
    if(!!sessionScope.lang)  {
        if(sessionScope.lang=="FR") {
            sessionScope.lang = "EN";       
        } else {
            sessionScope.lang = "FR";
        }
    } else {
        //since the default is FR, the first time it is clicked means we want to go to English
        sessionScope.lang = "EN";  
    }
    return; 
}}]]>
                </xe:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

How can I get the selected item value from the drop down and act upon it?  I need to set a session scope variable and do a full (or partial) refresh.

Thanks  :)

Comment: Hi Ben, we cover this in the Rapid XPages Dev course you got from TLCC. See the onItemClick event. This is in the Application Layout Design Framework lesson in Module 7. You have to add code to your onItemClick you already have since that one event does all the onclick events for the app layout.  Howard

Comment: Howard, I totally forgot I had that!!!  I didn't get much time to go through the course as my project started a lot sooner than expected.  The information is indeed there and quite helpful.  I guess I will take the time to go through the rest of it within the next few days.   ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add code to your onItemClick you already have since that one event does all the onclick events for the app layout.